# Mysterious Warning at logs

Tags: magento-1.9, error, template

In Magento log I see something like these:

```
2015-12-06T18:11:38+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(/app/design/frontend/..../..../template): failed to open stream: No such device  in /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php on line 241
2015-12-06T18:11:38+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening '/app/design/frontend/..../..../template' for inclusion (include_path='/app/code/local:/app/code/community:/app/code/core:/lib:.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php on line 241
2015-12-06T18:11:50+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(/app/design/frontend/..../..../template): failed to open stream: No such device  in /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php on line 241 
2015-12-06T18:11:50+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening '/app/design/frontend/..../..../template' for inclusion (include_path='/app/code/local:/app/code/community:/app/code/core:/lib:.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php on line 241
2015-12-06T18:24:58+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(/app/design/frontend/..../..../template): failed to open stream: No such device  in /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php on line 241 
2015-12-06T18:24:58+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening '/app/design/frontend/..../..../template' for inclusion (include_path='/app/code/local:/app/code/community:/app/code/core:/lib:.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php on line 241
```

In **Template.php** I see

```
 try {
            $includeFilePath = realpath($this->_viewDir . DS . $fileName);
            if (strpos($includeFilePath, realpath($this->_viewDir)) === 0 || $this->_getAllowSymlinks()) {
                include $includeFilePath;
            } else {
                Mage::log('Not valid template file:'.$fileName, Zend_Log::CRIT, null, null, true);
            }

        } catch (Exception $e) {
            ob_get_clean();
            throw $e;
        }
```

In 241 row -> `include $includeFilePath;`

Any idea what that warning is meaning?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fundamentals for debugging a Magento store](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/428/fundamentals-for-debugging-a-magento-store)

Comment: Magento tries to include the "template" directory itself as a template. Looks like some block is using an empty string "" or maybe "." as template file.

Answer (score 0):

Either a template file is missing or perhaps a template file is trying to include a file itself.

The odd portion is the four dots `....` as this isn't normal back referencing of `..`

You can add:

`Mage::log($includeFilePath, null, 'include-error.log');`

Before the `include $includeFilePath;` line,

Afterwards and check your `var/log/` for the `include-error.log` to see what full path it is trying to include to determine what the issue is.

Comment: I put .... instead of package and theme name

Comment: Ah, then most likely a template file being referenced somewhere doesn't exist or the filename/path for it is invalid.